# Gmail automatically marks emails as read

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

In the past few days Gmail has started automatically marking any new message as read. I deleted all filters, confirmed that no other device (including my phone) are logged in to Gmail. However when a new email arrives it is immediately marked as read.

Any ideas? This is driving me nuts.

Answer (score -1):

I realized I accidentally set up email forwarding in the "Forwarding and POP/IMAP" tab.

User error, but if anyone else makes the same silly mistake it is something to check.